# I've got some problems of iteration with my animation function (matplotlib.animation/Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create an animated histogram for work, using matplotlib.animation, but animation.FuncAnimation is not functioning properly : when using this code, that i found on the official documentation,

```
"""
A simple example of an animated plot
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))


def animate(i):
    print(i)
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,


# Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
     line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
     return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200),init_func=init,interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

I get as final result the graph created by init() function (an empty graph also), but no animate iterations. Furthermore, I tested other codes, which practically gave me the same result : i get the initialization, or the first frame, but not more. matplotlib and matplotlib.animation are installed, everything seems to be ok, except it doesn't work. Have someone an idea how to fix it ? (Thank you in advance :) !)

Comment: Where and how are you running this? Which versions of python, matplotlib do you have?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment x) ! I am running my programs under Python 3.6 with Spyder, in my IPython console, and my matplotlib version is 2.0.2 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that IPython inside your Spyder is configured to automatically use the inline backend. This would show your plots inside the console as png images. Of course png images cannot be animated.

I would suggest not to use IPython but execute the script in a dedicated Python console. In Spyder, go to Run/Configure.. and set the option to new dedicated Python console.

[image]

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot for this quick answer :) !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue working with Jupyter notebook and I solved it by inserting the line

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

in the code.